# Angularjs - Pass optional parameter for Directive from HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass an optional parameter *isvalid* from my html to the directive. I have followed all the steps mentioned in documentation but it still looks like i am doing something wrong.. i am not able to read the value in my directive. can you let me know what am i doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
 <customvideo isvalid="true"></div>
```

**MY Directive** 
**Update**: I had simplified for questioning  purpose and hence you were seeing $scope. I have updated the actual directive now

```
    // Set the directive
    angular
        .module('custom.directives')
        .directive('customvideo', customvideoDirective);

    // Set the directive $injections
    customvideoDirective.$inject = ['$Scope'];


 function customvideoDirective($Scope)  
{
            return {
                compile: compile,
                restrict: 'A',
                $Scope: {
                    isvalid: '=?'
                }
            };

  function compile() {
      console.log($Scope.isvalid);  //this is undefined 
     }
  }

})();
```

Comment: `$Scope` should be `scope`

Comment: thankyou @PankajParkar. i inject it as $scope. i removed it here for simplicity... it is something like this   :  // Set the directive
    angular
  .module('custom.directives')
  .directive('customvideo', customvideoDirective);

    // Set the directive $injections
    customvideoDirective.$inject = [
  '$Scope'
   ];

Comment: Please check my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

Change you `$Scope` property inside `Directive Definition Object` (DDO) should be changed `scope`. Also use `link` function instead of using `compile`, as `compile` function has access to only raw DOM, there will be no scope available in it. Even you can return and `PreLink`/`PostLink` from compile function, but in this case I believe using `link` would be appropriate.

```
angular.module('directives')
.directive('customvideo', function () {
    return {
       link: link,
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
          isvalid: '=?'
       }
    }
);

function link(scope) {
   console.log(scope.isvalid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to work it out.. not sure if it is the best.. but hey.. it works :)  Posting it here for those who come here for answers... 
I was writing the syntax for compile wrongly... I changed it to

```
 function  compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude)
  {
    // the tAttrs param has all the attributes associated with the element
    console.log(tAttrs.isvalid);
  }
```

Comment: This is not correct way of doing it. Compile function is not correct place to look for value passed to directive. please follow above answer..

Comment: Thanks Pankaj.. Would would mind explaining why not compile vs link in my scenario..  i dont want to modify my dom or anything.. i just want to read the value ..  I thought Link should be used when I actually want to modify the Dom. Would that be a wrong assumption?